# Angular 7 no me reconoce el modelo que estoy queriendo usar

Tags: angular, model, component

estoy intentando usar mi `usuario.model.ts` en mi componente `registro.component.ts` y me indica un **error** diciendo que **NO** encuentra la clase **usuario**: 
`ERROR in src/app/components/registro/registro.component.ts(11,11): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Usuario'.`

**CLASE registro.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-registro',
  templateUrl: './registro.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./registro.component.css']
})
export class RegistroComponent implements OnInit {

  usuario:Usuario;
constructor(){}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**CLASE usuario.model.ts**

```
export class Usuario{
    id: string;
    nombre: string;
    apellidos: string;
    usuario: string;
    email:string;
    password:string;
    fecha_registro:Date;
}
```

Los directorios de estos dos ficheros  son los siguientes:

```
app
 ..\componentes\registro\registro.component.ts
 ..\models\usuario.model.ts
```

Lo he intentado importar **a mano** pero ni aun asi me lo detecta.

Comment: Es muy extraño, debería poder importarlo usando: `import { Usuario } from '../../models/usuario.model';`

Comment: Posiblemente estas en JIT just in time compilando... Por lo que la creacion de esre nuevo archivo no se ha lanzado en el ng serve

Comment: Ah pues voy a reiniciarlo a ver.

Comment: Que va no funciona eso

Comment: ¿Qué sistema operativo estas usando?, prueba colocando la ruta completa ejemplo:

import { Usuario } 'src/app/models/usuario.model.ts';

Utiliza "/" no "\"

Comment: win 10 estoy usando, siempre me ha ido bien. No entiendo porque ahora no.

Comment: trata de usar usuario "u" minuscula, a mi me pasa que angular no reconoce rutas con mayusculas y minusculas